# PHP PDO bindValue() don't work

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

```
<?php
try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME", "USER", "PASSWD");

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM testdb ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT :index, 10");
    $stmt->bindValue(":index", $_GET['index'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    while( $r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
    {
        echo var_dump($r);                                      
    }

}
catch( PDOException $e )
{
    die("Exception");
}
```

The problem is on this line: `$stmt->bindValue(":index", $_GET['index'], PDO::PARAM_INT);`

And the specific parameter is the second one.

The code as it is above doesn't work, it doesn't return anything so the while loop isn't executed. If I replace $_GET['index'] with a number, like 10, it works just fine, it returns 10 rows. Echoing $_GET['index'] displays a number, so it should pass a number. I've also tried bindParam, but the result is same.

Why isn't this working?

EDIT:

Interesting... If I replace `$_GET['index'] with (int)$_GET['index']` it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check $stmt->errorInfo() you will actually find that your query failed.

PDO::PARAM_INT tells PDO that you are giving it an integer. If you do not give PDO an integer, PDO will quote the value in the sql string.

```
SELECT id, name FROM testdb ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT "1", 10
```

All values in $_GET are either an array or a string. You did the correct thing by coercing $_GET['index'] to an integer before binding it as a value. By doing this, PDO gets an integer, was expecting an integer from PDO::PARAM_INT, and therefore will not quote the value in the sql string.

```
SELECT id, name FROM testdb ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Values in the `$_GET` super-global array are strings : PHP doesn't guess what's passed iin the querystring.

If you want one value from `$_GET` to be considered as an integer -- which is what you want, here -- you'll need to convert it to an integer yourself.

In order to do that, you can use :

- A [**`typecast`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) : `(int)$_GET['yourval']`
- The [**`intval()`**](http://www.php.net/intval) function, which allows one to specific the base that's to be used

Comment: Values in the $_GET super-global array can also be arrays. http://php.net/manual/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like $_GET['index'] is not what you expect it to be. Use var_dump() to inspect the value closer. Pay attention to the length of the string that var_dump reports, because some characters are not visually detectable, but the length of the string will tell the hidden story.

Comment: page.php?index=10 gives string(2) "10".